# Find all the values of parameter a for which there are infinite solutions?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have the following sets of equations:

[image]

and I need to find the a parameter. When I see such a thing I instantly tackle the problem with Gauss-Jordan matrix method. But I get stuck somehow. Is there another approach to such problem? I think I've seen limits involved for getting the solution but I can't track the website where I've seen that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauss-Jordan is probably your best bet here.  If you put your system into the augmented matrix
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & a+1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4a+1 & 2
\end{array}\right),
\end{equation}
you can use Gauss-Jordan to row-reduce this to
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1-4a & -2\\
0 & 1 & 4a & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1-4a^2 & 1-2a
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
If you can choose a value for $a$ that makes both $1-4a^2$ and $1-2a$ equal $0$, then your bottom row will be all zero.  Assuming the top two rows are still consistent, your system should have infinitely many solutions.  Given the last matrix above, can you choose $a$ so that your system has *no* solutions?

Comment: Yes I can. Now I see that I've missed something in my calculations. Tnx for the quick reply, running late with my exam tomorow.. I'l accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Gauss-Jordan will work fine for this.  Another approach is to expand the determinant and find the value(s) of $a$ that make it zero.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Determinant%22,%20%22detmatrix%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,a%2B1,2%7D,%7B1,2,4a%2B1%7D%7D%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22determinant%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) tells us the determinant is $4a^2-1$, so the candidates are $\pm \frac 12$  One leads to inconsistent equations, the other to redundant ones.